# Using pageable and still querying for every possible item

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

To speed up our application we were planning on limiting the amount of results we get when executing a query. The problem is that a simple LIMIT doesn't work with JPQL, so we're trying to create a workaround using Pageables.

The result is that the correct amount of results get visualized, which is excellent, but it takes way longer than expected and when monitoring the executed queries it seems that it's still querying for every single object instead of the requested amount. Looks like it's filtering 'after' it retrieved the complete result.

The Repository:

```
public interface CompRepository extends JpaRepository<Comp, Integer> {
...

    @Query(value = "select distinct c from Comp c" +
            " left join fetch c.titles ti " +
            " left join fetch c.messages msg  " +
            " where c.status = 'PUBLISHED' " +
            " order by c.id desc",
        countQuery = "select count(c) from Comp c")
    Page<Compass> findByLatest(Pageable page);

...
}
```

The service:

```
public class CompService {
    @Autowired
    private CompRepository repository;
...

    public static List<Comp> findLatest() {
        int amount = 5; /*hardcoded*/

        Page<Compass> page = getRepository().findByLatest(new PageRequest(1, amount).first());

        return page.getContent();
    }

...
}
```

Pom:

```
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
....
```

If you need more code: shout!

Does anybody have an idea what the problem might be?

If not, any suggestion on a better way to find away around the lack of LIMIT in JPQL?

**___SOLUTION___**

Removing the joins fixed it. More specifically, the problem lies with the 'fetch', so I could choose to keep the joins if I removed the 'fetch' from the query, but I don't think there's any use in that.

Comment: "Lack of LIMIT in Hibernate"? You mean the fact that __JPQL__ does not have such a keyword, though does have firstResult/maxResults ?

Comment: You're right, I tend to see JPA and Hibernate as 2 sides of the same blade, because it's always a combination in our projects :-) Edited the original post. I will check out the maxresult option, but I believe we tried that in the past without satisfying results. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Is there an annotation for maxResults? We're using the JpaRepository interface, so adding maxResults as a method is not exactly an option and when looking for a workaround people keep suggesting Pageables.

Comment: Look at the generated SQL. Now try modifying that SQL query to use limit to retrieve the same information. You won't be able to, because your query is fetching two collections.So, although you only want 10 Compass, the amount of rows being retrieved can be 10, 100, 1000, 10000, you just don't know. Remobe the fetch joins, and the query will use limit.

Comment: Removing the joins fixed the problem, thank you! If you formulate this into a post, I'll mark it as the answer!